# Nested Sets model or some other model for representing hierarchy?

Tags: python, xml, hierarchical-data, nested-sets, flat

I have a project where I hope to store hierarchical information (specifically, categories and subcategories) in what is basically a flat database system (in short, it's a collection of XML records). I'd like to store information about categories and subcategories in the system:

- Animals

  - Invertebrates
  - Vertebrates
- Weather
- Buildings

  - Skyscrapers
  - Historic buildings

...and so forth.

*Everything* in the system, for better or worse, is stored as an XML record; this is just how the storage system works.

Which means that each category in the system is also stored as an XML record, like so:

```
<record id="12345">
   <attribute name="Skyscrapers" />
   <attribute type="Category" />
</record>
```

So I am wondering how to implement a hierarchy under these constraints.

I'm used to data storage in a relational database. In those cases I pretty much always use the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). It seems like this wouldn't be a good choice in this case because:

1. Each time you insert an item, you
   have to change the `right` and/or
   `left` values for many of the nodes.
   I can't do a bulk update on the XML
   files, so I'd have to update each
   one individually.
2. Although there are search functions that let me filter by
   "less-than" or "greater-than" (so I
   could in theory pull only the
   relevant child nodes or parent nodes
   of a given category), I can't order
   the XML records by attributes. So
   I'd have to retrieve all of the
   documents, transform them into a
   list of objects that can be sorted
   (in this case with Python) and then
   sort them using a `lambda` function.

Since my data storage model isn't significantly different than storing data using NoSQL I was wondering if anyone using that storage mechanism has come up with a good trick for handling and storing hierarchical data.

Answer (score 1):

This class (based on the [Peewee ORM](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) allows you to handle hierarchical data with a flat relational database (PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite are supported):

https://github.com/mathieurodic/peewee-tree/blob/master/node.py

You can make a few changes in the class methods so the changes are also applied to the XML file you are manipulating.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. I don't consider MySQL, SQLite, or PostgreSQL to be "flat" databases… I can easily use the nested model with any of them. For this use case I needed something that worked in an actual flat database (think hash key).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how applicable this would be for your use case, but as a thought, maybe using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) will help. Perhaps it's default hierarchical representation will be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: No BeautifulSoup is about parsing HTML or XHTML. It has zilch to do with handling, storing, and organizing hierarchical data.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the question, I thought you were asking about how to represent your data in code rather than persisted storage. Sorry about that.